# How to download torrent specific files in python code?

Tags: python, bittorrent, aria2

In my system I usually use command line aria2c like this

```
$ aria2c my_torrent_file.torrent -S
$ aria2c my_torrent_file.torrent --select-file=1,4-8,10
```

How can I do the same with aria2p in my python code?